# How can I check to see if an object is an instance of a certain set of prototypes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, indexof

I know I can check to see if an object contains any instances of a prototype like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {

    if ((obj[key] instanceof head) || (obj[key] instanceof body)) {

        console.log("Key Accepted: " + obj[key]);

    }

}
```

And I know I can check to see if an object is a member of a list of objects:

```
var fruitBasket = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
if (fruitBasket.indexOf("Apple") !== -1) {

    console.log("There's an apple in this fruit basket!");

}
```

But how can I check to see if an object is an instance of a certain set of prototypes?

Comment: I'm not even sure how I would associate the prototypes with each other as a list.

Comment: This link has all the answers for all types of checking: http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/ . i knew an even more thorough guide, but I forgot the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your browser supports it (IE9+), you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on an array of classes/functions.

```
var obj = ...,
    result = [Array, Number, Foo].some(function(clas) { return obj instanceof clas; });
```

`result` will be `true` if `obj` is an instance of `Array`, `Number` or `Foo`.

Without the `some` method you can simply iterate over the array with a `for`.

Comment: Without `some`, just shim it :-)

Comment: Indeed that might be an even better idea.